# 2-bay NAS - start with a single 8TB drive and get a second later?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, nas, synology-diskstation

Just ordered a Synology DS220+ NAS and a Seagate 8TB Ironwolf NAS drive to go inside.

I'm hoping to start with this and get a second drive later for Raid 1 (mirroring) or perhaps Synology Hybrid RAID.

This is my first NAS/RAID device and wondered if it will mess things up to start with a single drive and migrate to a second later?

Background waffle

Btw, I realise that while it's a single drive configuration, it will be "unprotected" but this NAS is itself an extra backup for a 4TB drive which is also backed up to Backblaze. Having just lost a drive, it became clear that I was 100% reliant on Backblaze and it would take weeks to download 4TB of data, hence purchasing the NAS to go alongside the replacement 4TB drive.

Comment: Many NAS units do indeed let you change disk RAID modes, whether or not the mode change is destructive depends on the type of change and the system itself. I would expect going from a single disk to RAID 1 to be completely fine, but going to RAID 0 may well erase all disks. Other modes would depend on the manufacturer and be stated in their manuals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I also managed to get a reply from Synology who more or less confirmed I'd be able to migrate from No RAID to RAID 1 easily.